# What is the most efficient way to update existing records using EF core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am getting data from an external API and then using Entity Framework Core to insert the data into a table that has an identity field which is the primary key. I plan to regularly update the table with data from the API. There will be new records, and records that need to be updated.

I struggling to determine what the best approach is to update existing records because the data from the API does not contain the primary key as this is generated when data is inserted into the table. The API data does contain another unique id that I could use to look up the primary key before performing an update.

I am hoping someone has an example of a clean approach to performing the updates.

Comment: I recommend reading this doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward thing to do is:

1. Make sure you have an index on that other unique id
2. Look up the entity using that other unique id
3. Save the data coming in on the API request into the entity
4. Save changes

The more complicated thing to do would be something like:

```
context.DbSetForEntity.ExecuteRawSQL("Update Entity Set blaa blaa blaa where externalId={0}", externalId)..
```

The second approach is much harder to get right and maintain and overall will not be that much faster, just a few milliseconds. I'd go with the first approach.

A good maxim to follow is to defer optimization until you see that you need it.

By the way, if you really want to experiment with the performance you might want to try running the queries in LinqPad. The free edition should be enough to give you timing without having to put it all in your code.